# 'Join' two models in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that display editable values.  One of those values is an id of a user.  I don't want to display the id of the user I want to display the users name.

I do this and it works great:

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="type">Point of Contact</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select ng-model="device.poc" ng-options="user._id as user.username for user in users">
        </select>
      </div>
```

Now I am trying to display a list of all devices in a non-editable form so I loop devices with an ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices | filter:{registered: true}" class="top-gap">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
          {{device.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
          {{device.poc}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

But device.poc is not what I want to display, I want to display the users name that is attached to that device.  In the mustaches '{{}}' can I 'join' to the users model like I did in the select so I can display the users name?

Comment: Why not simply add a function `getUserById()` to your controller scope, which you would call using `{{ getUserById(device.poc).username }}`? Or iterate through the devices when they're fetched and add a user object into each of them, to be able to use `{{ device.user.username }}`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want your device.poc property to hold the user object, change your ng-options to:

```
user.username for user in users
```

Then you should be able to do

```
{{device.poc.username}}
```

And where you need id, device.poc._id

Comment: oh sorry ng-options already works, please re-read the question.  I want that type of functionality outside of a select box.

Comment: If device.poc is set to your user object, then I'm not sure what the problem is I guess. If you require that device.poc be set to only the user's id, then you'll need a lookup function like JB Nizet suggested.

Comment: correct I need a lookup function.  Although I did not for the select, wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Well the select uses the ng-options directive to declare a behind the scenes lookup function via a specific expression grammar for that purpose. The {{ }} syntax is for generic expression evaluations so you need to provide your own lookup method.